# In Bitbucket Pipelines, can manual pipelines present descriptions in the web interface?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

In Bitbucket Pipelines, for manually run pipelines (i.e. "custom pipelines") where you use the web UI to set *variables*, is it possible to insert any documentation? For example, so that the UI presents a *description* above or alongside the input form for a variable? (Or are you limited only to being able to name the pipeline and optionally give the variables each a default value and a set of allowed values?)

I don't want other users of the same pipeline (from the web UI) to misinterpret what a keyword expects, or indeed what the pipeline will do, and doubt they will always refer the source code itself to find comments.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know.

Documentation only describes a `name`, `default` and `allowed-values` attributes https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/#variables

But I think the culprit of your issue boils down to a general programming problem: adequately naming variables. Comments making up for bad variable names is among the top-10 programming bad practices.

Variable names should always be unambiguous and self-explanatory for anyone reading it.